# HTML code gets displayed in signature card

Tags: html, outlook

I created a signature card using `HTML`. But sometimes when I attach or send reply using the card, its respective `HTML` code is displayed and not the card.

Have anyone faced these kind of problems?

Comment: Can you provide the code you have?

Comment: Here is the code updated

Comment: Is that when you reply to a plain text (non-HTML) email?

Comment: It happens in both the cases, to plain as well as to html emails.

Comment: Assuming you are using Outlook, it's common that emails you receive / send may LOOK like HTML, but are actually Rich Text (a common default for Outlook).   When you are sending emails (or replying), you can always click on the Format Text tab to see if you are sending it in HTML, Plain Text, or Rich Text.

Answer (score 0):

(This is a total re-write of my previous answer.)

When creating a signature in Outlook, don't manually add HTML.  Add whatever you words/fonts/colors/images that you want in your signature, and Outlook will automagically create the necessary HTML for you.

[image]

Bottom line:  This is not really a programming question.

Comment: So I select E-mail Security in Trust Center and I check first option" Encrypt contents and attachments for outgoing messages" and click on settings. In there I select Cryptography option as S/MIME. My questions is where I can find this content type header to text/html.

Comment: S/MIME has nothing to do with this.  Question:  Are you writing your own email client, or are you using an existing client (such as Outlook)?

Comment: I am using Outlook for email.